# There is no link in the verification email for a new Apple ID I created

Tags: apple-id

I got my new iPhone today and ofcrouse made an Apple ID right away. Everything goes ok, I get sent a verification email, but there is no link in it. It has the instructions and they mention a link, but there is none. I tried sending the verification email from my iPhone and from the apple site (https://appleid.apple.com/), but still nothing.

Here is a screenshot of the email I received:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It seems that your email client is **not displaying images**. (Many email programs disable images by default for security purposes.) However, the verification link will probably be an image button, so **you must enable images in order to see it**.

(Alternatively, if you configure your email account in Mail on your iPhone, you should also be able to see the button there, since Mail displays images in emails.)

Answer (score 1):

Set up your e mail account on your new I phone. Then open apples verification e Mail on your phones e mail app. The rest is easy.The email on my home computer (windows) HP didn't have the link, hours wasted and several beers consumed.